# My laptop does not detect two rams

Tags: laptop, memory

I'm using **Lenovo E450** and it has two ram slots.
Recently I bought another 4GB ram to upgrade to 8GB.
But when I put two 4GB rams together, Computer only cognizes
new bought one.
I tried putting the ram in alternating slots, but both of slots and ram works if only one ram exist.
See my photos below for detail.

[Ram Image. Right one is new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w441A.jpg)

[On CPUZ, it says 8GB. But on task manager it says 4GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UDmV.jpg)

[Slot 1 Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3fRV.jpg)
[Slot 2 Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzPwJ.jpg)
[Translation : Slot 1 : empty, Slot 2 : 4GB 1600Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvxvX.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two completely different types of RAM, which are not compatible with each other.  One is PC3-12800, while the other is PC3-10700.  You need to purchase an identical RAM module as your original RAM stick.  Your original appears to be a DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800), so you should return the RAM you purchased and get another DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800).